# How to scrape website data into an Excel worksheet?

Tags: javascript, java, html, excel, web-scraping

I'm a novice programmer trying to compile an Excel list of all the inc5000 companies and their industry, location, revenue, and CEO. Is there any way for me to automate this so that I don't have to manually input all 5000?

Some issues:

-The inc5000 list only displays 50 companies on a page, and scrolling to the next page does not change the URL. I tried converting the URL into HTML, but none of the metadata actually shows up in the HTML code (I used https://try.jsoup.org/~LGB7rk_atM2roavV0d-czMt3J_g).

-All of the information I need is on this one scrolling page (https://www.inc.com/profile/loot-crate), but the URL changes for each company as you progress down the page. Is there any way to grab the data from this site without manually changing 5000 URLs?

I'm really new to programming and I know next to nothing about HTML/JavaScript/Web design-- I only know basic Java. I would really appreciate any help or potential leads into a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to go through the [question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What have you tried so far? Post some code HERE, and identify specific problems in that code for
 us to help you with.

Comment: Sorry about the miscommunication- I don't have any code, because I'm asking about how I can approach this problem and start.

Comment: This could be a harder way, but you could write something in Java that calls on Selenium to automate the browser grab the value of each field, writes it out to Excel, and then hits the next company button.

Comment: @SherryFeng - did you try my answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the easy way:

Go to the page, hit f12, go to the "Network" tab of debug tools, select XHR (to filter to only the data calls) then scroll to the bottom of the page.  The page makes a query for each company, that you can access in the debug tools.

Once you have all the pages, you can highlight all the rows in the file name list to the left, right click, and save it to a .har file.

From there, just write a script to pull out the json and you're set.

[image]